# Instantiate with const definition

Tags: javascript

So could anyone lead me in the right direction regarding instantiation? I have the following:

```
const menus = wp.api.collections.Posts.extend({
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/locations/favorites_launcher',
})
const Menus = new menus();
```

How could I instantiate the above without calling a separate line: `const Menus = new menus()` - Is there a shorthand for that?

Comment: u meant by without storing into a variable?

Comment: Honestly I don't think it's worthwhile because it also makes the code harder to read. I would also suggest switching up your capitalization to:

`const Menus = wp.api.collections.Posts.extend({
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/locations/favorites_launcher',
});
const menus = new Menus();`

Use TitleCase for classes and snake_case or camelCase for instances of classes.

Comment: Thanks @AbirTaheer, I wasn't sure if there was a simpler way, but now I see how it could be much harder to read.

Comment: You have your `M` and `m` backwards. The convention that the majority of javascript programmers use is that capital letters means a class and small letters mean a value or object. If it's a small hobby project that only you will use then it's not much of a problem but if you're planning on sharing this code or work on it with others then it's better to follow normal convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Menus = new (wp.api.collections.Posts.extend({
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/locations/favorites_launcher',
}))();
```

Doable? I guess. Worth it? I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are working with maybe try

```
const Menus = new wp.api.collections.Posts.extend({
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/locations/favorites_launcher',
})
```